# Why isn't Steam working on 18.04LTS?

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

I'm having a problem with getting Steam to work. The output of the issue is different from the other questions I've seen so far and they were on 16.04LTS. I installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS yesterday from a USB instead of sticking with 16.04LTS. On 16.04 I installed it from the Ubuntu repositories and had no problems whatsoever however doing the same on 18.04 didn't work out so well. After installing Steam it opened and downloaded and installed updates but the account wizard doesn't open after that and if I click on the app icon it doesn't either. Next I tried to run it from the terminal to see if there would be any errors and I got the following:

```
vampirefox2@DESKTOP-PYD23:~$ steam 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/vampirefox2/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why this error is displayed. I've never seen it before. I tried purging it and deleting the `.steam` cache folder and reinstalling but I had no luck. Can anyone help me fix this? I really want to game on Ubuntu.Thanks for reading :)

PS: I have the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed and I remember seeing a message on the installation prompt saying:

```
  Recommended packages:
  nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386
```

Don't know if this might be part or the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found out a solution I have no idea what made decide to do this but it worked. I decided to go and look in the `.steam` folder in the home directory and saw a `steam.sh` script in which I then ran from the terminal. A pop up window came up saying "Extracting Package" and behold the login wizard popped up. Everything works now and even when I select it from the apps launcher that works also. :)

Comment: I had the same issue, and this worked for me.  Thank you

Comment: This is kinda late but your welcome. :)